# MSSQL linked server supplied inconsistent metadata for a column

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I'm facing a difficult to run 'SUM' syntax from a linked server(PostgreSQL) in MSSQL, the connection created via ODBC driver.

If I only retrieve the data, there isn't any problem,

```
select * from OpenQuery([192.168.1.145],'
    select party_code, amount_forex from biv_so_main
')
```

If I try to sum the value, it throws an error,

```
select * from OpenQuery([192.168.1.145],'
    select party_code, sum(amount_forex) from biv_so_main group by party_code
')
```

Error message

`The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "192.168.1.145" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "sum" (compile-time ordinal 2) of object "
select party_code, sum(amount_forex) from biv_so_main group by party_code
" was reported to have a "SCALE" of 6 at compile time and 2 at run time.`

I googled a lot, seems nobody has the same issue like me, anybody can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an alias to your sum column and cast into a datatype (into whatever type amount_forex is).

```
select * from OpenQuery([192.168.1.145],'
    select party_code
         , sum(amount_forex)::int amount_forex_sum 
    from biv_so_main group by party_code
')
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! but why SUM makes the type unmatched or unknown?

Comment: If you look at the output from "\da sum" in psql you will see the signatures for all the SUM() aggregates. The output is often of a larger datatype than the inuput values - in the version I have locally a sum of bigint values will return a numeric. If the linked server assumes that the types will be the same (at plan time) it will get an unhappy surprise when the returned values (at run time) are of larger scale.

Comment: Thanks! `sum(x)::int xsum`  was the key to my problem!